# When I include a module in another which has already been included in a class, the new methods are not accessible to the class

Tags: ruby

Here is some code demonstrating the behavior I'm talking about:

```
module A
  def foo; end
end

# initialize B with no methods
module B; end

class C
  include B
end

# add methods to B
module B
  def foo; end
  include A
end

C.new.foo
C.new.bar # error: instance method bar is not defined for C
```

So `def`s added to B are reflected in C, whereas added `include`s are not (unless B is re-included afterwards). Why is this, and is there a clean way around it?

Comment: Where is `bar` supposed to come from? I see `foo` in `A` and `B` but no `bar` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

When you `include` a module `M` in a class `C`, this is what happens:

1. Ruby creates a class (let's call it `⟦M′⟧`) whose method table pointer, constant table pointer and class variable table pointer point to `M`'s method table, constant table and class variable table.
2. `⟦M′⟧`'s superclass pointer is set to `C`'s superclass.
3. `C`'s superclass pointer is set to `⟦M′⟧`.

If there are modules `include`ed in `M`, this process is applied recursively.

Note that the recursive flattening of mixins is applied *once*, when you call `include`. Any changes in the inheritance hierarchy that are made afterwards will *not* be reflected.

However, when you add a method to `M`'s method table, that change will be reflected, because there is only *one* method table, to which both `M` and `⟦M′⟧` refer.